# How to call dbms_application_info with EntityManager injection

Tags: jpa, cdi

We are building a Java EE / JPA / CDI app with an Oracle Database. The data model (this we can't change) implements security partly by using views and client_info...something like..

```
create view the_view
as select * 
from the_table
where organization_id = USERENV('CLIENT_INFO')
```

where userenv('CLIENT_INFO') is basically set by calling

```
dbms_application_info.set_client_info(11);
```

Now, we have a series of Stateless Beans that basically inject Persistence Context and execute queries (both native queries and regular POJO) and we need a way to inject the client info (that we can get from the security context) into the  PersistenceContext before making calls to the EntityManager

in a nutshell I need to be able to call this..

```
@PersistenceContext 
EntityManager em;

@Inject
UserInfo userInfo;

public TheView getTableData(long id) {
    // At this point security Information should be set.. 
    // Call the query
    return em.find(TheView.class, id);

}
```

without having to call a setClientInfo() manually..

One way of doing this would probably be using interceptors and annotate the method and make the call there (providing I can get hold of the PersistenceContext that the method will use.. ).. will this even work??

Any other way of doing this??

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interceptor approach you are writing about sounds like an excellent fit.

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your requirements correctly, but it seems as if would be a good idea to decouple authorization logic from the actual business logic to be able to write something like this:

...

```
@IsEditor("someMoreData")
public X getData() {
 ...
}
```

`IsEditor` is an interceptor and will encapsulate the relevant DB lookup.

Seam Security as an independent CDI modules comes with a couple of concepts (& implementations), you should definitely [check it out](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html/security-authorization.html).

Comment: If what's in Apache DeltaSpike (https://cwiki.apache.org/DeltaSpike/) will work for you, please use DeltaSpike. Seam 3 is no longer being developed and all efforts are being put into DeltaSpike.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EclipseLink, there is some info here on using EclipseLink with Oracle VPD, which seems similar.

Nasically, you can use events to execute your call.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Shared_and_Isolated#Oracle_Virtual_Private_Database_.28VPD.29

Comment: UNfortunatly this is not an option, the problem is that the application I'm trying to connect to is a third party application that can't be modified (Oracle EBS) wich handles part of their security using views, so VPD are note an option...